# Is there a targetEnvironment for macCatalyst in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, target, catalyst

how to make a conditional view in SwiftUI with a targetEnvironment which checks for macCatalyst?

Something like:

```
#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
    print("macOS")
#else
    print("Your regular code")
#endif
```

But directly in SwiftUI

Comment: This might depend on context, so would you show your code, what and where do you want conditionally to show something?

Comment: I want to show a button only when im in the Mac app and not in the iPhone/iPad app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
            Button("Catalyst Demo") { }
#endif
            Text("Hello, World!")
        }.frame(width: 300, height: 200)
    }
}
```